# OpenShift Online: European Hosting

Tags: java, openshift

How can I convert existing application from US hosting location(*aws-us-east-1 region*) to European hosting location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use the rhc snapshot command,  to do a backup of the existing application, then create a new gear in the ea location and do an rhc snapshot restore to that gear, or the rhc create-app with the --from-app.
You can check out these resources for more specific information:

1. https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/203265710-How-can-I-move-an-existing-application-from-the-US-aws-us-east-1-hosting-region-to-the-European-aws-eu-west-1-hosting-region-
2. https://developers.openshift.com/en/overview-platform-features.html#_migrating_an_existing_application_to_another_region_or_zone

Comment: and here is the surprise: _Small gears cannot be deployed to this (aws-eu-west-1) region. Only production gears can be deployed_